# How to refund to multiple transactions in authorize .net using single refund transaction

Tags: c#, authorize.net

We are using authorize.net on our Website. We are offering multiple payments (EMI's) for a single product on our website. Now some users wants refund after say 4-5 payments. How to implement this using single transaction?

Issues:

1) We have implemented refunds functionality provided by API but this only refunds the amount which is equal to or less to amount paid.

I have searched and found there is unlinked Credit card feature. We have activated this on our account by still there is no code available, we are using C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using a single transaction. Each AUTH_CAPTURE must be refunded individually.